# Java: Split string by number of characters but with guarantee that string will be split only after whitespace

Tags: java, string

I want to achieve something like this.

```
String str = "This is just a sample string";

List<String> strChunks = splitString(str,8);
```

and `strChunks` should should be like:

```
"This is ","just a ","sample ","string."
```

Please note that string like "sample " have only 7 characters as with 8 characters it will be "sample s" which will break down my next word "string".

Also we can go with the assumption that a word will never be larger than second argument of method (which is 8 in example) because in my use case second argument is always static with value 32000.

The obvious approach that I can think of is looping thru the given string, breaking the string after 8 chars and than searching the next white space from the end. And then repeating same thing again for remaining string.

Is there any more elegant way to achieve the same. Is there any utility method already available in some standard third libraries like Guava, Apache Commons.

Comment: You should probably add a "more" general description of what you want to achieve. For example what should be the result for "This is just another extraordinary sample string" where you have words longer than 8 chars.

Comment: What happens if one of the word is longer than x (8) characters long?

Comment: `"just a "` has only seven characters.

Comment: So does `"sample "`.

Comment: I think the point is having as many whole words as possible, up to (but not exactly) N characters..

Comment: I can skip that possibility of word larger than second argument as in my use case the second argument value will be always static 32000. And it is guaranteed that input string will never have word larger than 32000 chars.

Comment: I get the impression, from the example and the description, that at each stage you want to take the biggest chunk that ends with a space and doesn't exceed 8 characters. Yes?

Comment: What are we doing with repeated whitespace? Or do you really mean that there will only ever be spaces, and only one space at a time?

Answer (score 4):

Splitting on `"(?<=\\G.{7,}\\s)"` produces the result that you need ([demo](http://ideone.com/VEyVU1)).

`\\G` means the end of previous match; `.{7,}` means seven or more of any characters; `\\s` means a space character.

Comment: @chiastic-security Yes, because the example in the question has a mistake.

Comment: Btw will this still be linear for large split sizes? (OP wants 32000.) I expect so but the processing of regexes is a bit of a black box to me.

Comment: @chiastic-security I mean OP mis-counted the number of characters, allowing `"sample "` and `"just a "` in the output, despite being one character shorter than his declared 8-character limit.

Comment: No, no, I think that meets the spec. I don't think that's a mistake. I think he wants 8 chars to be a maximum, not a minimum. And taking one more char in those cases would split the following word.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I think there is no mistake in question. I have updated the description to avoid confusion.

Comment: if changing the regex to `{0,8}` instead of `{7,}` it seems that the lookbehind is non-greedy so that the result is: `[This , is , just , a , sample , string]`

Comment: This code fails for input `"This is just a sample s t r ing but harder"`, which produces 2 fragments incorrectly longer than 8. See [demo](http://ideone.com/XdOPgf). I thought of using `\G` too, but I don't think it can be done without a train wreck alternation counting down from length 7 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Not a standard method, but this might suit your needs

See it on http://ideone.com/2RFIZd

```
public static List<String> splitString(String str, int chunksize) {
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0;
    for(char character : chars) {
        if(count < chunksize - 1) {
            builder.append(character);
            count++;
        }
        else {
            if(character == ' ') {
                builder.append(character);
                list.add(builder.toString());
                count = 0;
                builder.setLength(0);
            }
            else {
                builder.append(character);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    list.add(builder.toString());
    builder.setLength(0);
    return list;
}
```

Please note, I used the human notation for string length, because that's what your sample reflects( 8 = postion 7 in string). that's why the `chunksize - 1` is there.

This method takes 3 milliseconds on a text the size of http://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/enhancements/fy0711/2006051179-s.html

Answer (score 0):

- Splitting String using method 1.

  ```
  String text="This is just a sample string";
  List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
  int index = 0;
  while (index < text.length()) {
      strings.add(text.substring(index, Math.min(index + 8,text.length())));
      index += 8;
  }
  for(String s : strings){
      System.out.println("["+s+"]");
  }
  ```
- Splitting String using Method 2

  ```
  String[] s=text.split("(?<=\\G.{"+8+"})");
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("["+s[i]+"]");
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This uses a hacked reduction to get it done without much code:

```
String str = "This is just a sample string";
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
parts.add(Arrays.stream(str.split("(?<= )"))
  .reduce((a, b) -> { 
    if (a.length() + b.length() <= 8)
        return a + b;
    parts.add(a); 
    return b;
  }).get());
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/VmYZWC) using edge case input (that breaks some other answers!)

This splits after each space, then either joins up parts or adds to the list depending on the length of the pair.